# How to keep navbar centered when stickied?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

When working on a recent project, I wanted to add a scroll-then-fix header. I researched this thouroughly, but many of the online sources were of little help, as they relied on older versions of various languages or relied to extensively on unexplained 'magic numbers'. Eventually, I decided to simply code it myself, and produced the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elementPosition = $('#navbar').offset();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
            $('#navbar').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
        } else {
            $('#navbar').css('position', 'static');
}})});
```

This has worked to sticky the navbar to the top, but whenever it activates it stickies it to the top left instead of maintaining its centered position. All I'm changing is the 'position' and adding the attribute 'top', so I see no reason for it to suddenly shift sideways. I would hugely appreciate any fixes or explanations you may have. For reference, here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="navbar"><ul>
    <li id="activePage"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Upcoming events </a><li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contribute</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

and css:

```
#navbar {
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
}

#navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#navbar li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}

#navbar ul #activePage a {
    color: #cec8c8;
}

#navbar li a {
    color: black;
    padding: 14px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any and all help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that an absolutely or fixed positioned element will only take up the amount of space on screen as the contents inside of it. So the element is going from a default block element that will occupy 100% width of the screen, to a fixed positioned element occupying only the width it needs from the content inside.

An easy way to address this is to add `left: 0; right: 0;` to the element, telling it to span the width of the window viewport.

You can do that by changing this line

```
$('#navbar').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
```

to

```
$('#navbar').css('position', 'fixed').css({'top':'0','left':'0','right':'0'});
```

You can also assign `width: 100%;` to the element instead, but then you need to be mindful of any box model issues that might arise, or use `box-sizing: border-box;` to keep the nav from extending beyond the width of the viewport in case you're using any padding or borders that might cause the width to expand beyond 100%.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. One question: if you can do things like `.css({'top':'0','left':'0','right':'0'})`, could I have combined the `.css('position', 'fixed')` as well to get `.css({'top':'0','left':'0','right':'0','position', 'fixed'});`?

Comment: @Bugsy np! Yep, you can combine them like that. Alternatively, a cleaner way to do it would be to put all of those CSS properties in a class like `.sticky` and you use jQuery to `$.addClass('sticky');` and `$.removeClass('sticky');` based on your `scrollTop()` conditional.